# R: How to count elements within each cells after aggregate command

Tags: r

Original `my.data`:

```
my.data <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,2,2,2),
  Value = c(3,4,2.1,3.4,5)
)

ID        Value
1         3
1         4
2         2.1
2         3.4
2         5
```

The data is consolidated by `aggregate` as below

```
consol <- aggregate(Value ~ID, my.data, paste)
```

`consol` looks like this:

```
ID      Value
1       c("3", "4")
2       c("2.1", "3.4", "5")
```

How can I count the number of elements of `value` in `consol`? Even though `consol[1,2]` shows `"3" "4"`, `length(consol[1,2])` gives the value of `1`. Actually all cells in the column of `Value` gives a length of `1`.  I expect to get length of 2 for `consol[1,2]` and length of 3 for `consol[2,2]`.

Comment: For your specific question of counting the number of elements by ID, you just have to use table(my.data$ID)

Comment: Are you intentionally converting your numbers to characters into `consol`? You could achieve the same aggregation with `aggregate(Value~ID, my.data, c)`, where `$Value` is a list of various length elements. However, the elements are still numeric (true to the data source), so you won't have num-char conversion loss.

Comment: You know you're not actually pasting anything, right?  It might be better to show us what output you want from `aggregate()` and get that fixed.  The way you're doing it produces an undesirable list column.  Seems you may just want `aggregate(Value ~ ID, my.data, length)`

Comment: based on @xraynaud's suggestions, the problem solved. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
lapply(consol$Value, function(x) length(x))
```

Comment: Or just `lengths(consol$Value)`.

Comment: or more simply `lapply(consol$Value, length)`

Comment: That is not simpler. `lengths` is a better function here by "codegolf" (7 chars shorter) , by "speed" (25% faster on small data, 3 orders of magnitude faster with 10000 rows), and arguably by "readability" (admittedly a subjective metric).

Answer (score 0):

The elements are aggregated to a list. There is only one list in the field, but the list has multiple elements. So, to get the number of elements in the list you will need to open it like this:

```
length(consol[1,2][[1]])
```

See also:

```
class(consol[1,2])
> [1] "list"
class(consol[1,2][[1]])
> [1] "character"
```